# Yii 2 Cinema seat style Form

Tags: php, forms, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have a project where the user can buy ticket for a movie in a cinema and there's an opportunity for booking seats.
My problem is the seat booking because I have to make a special form like this:

[image]

And the user select seats in this mosaic and after submit the form the seat number (like 15) and the serial number (like  1F or 3I) saved to database.

Comment: In my experience, the real challenge is not the identifier (seat 15, 1F, 3I) and the irregular seating plan. It is also not the framework you use YII2 / CI , etc. (you just need to create a special view and associate the seats with clickable DIVs) Usually such kind of system will be used by MORE THAN ONE STAFF , or opened so that buyers can buy the tickets themselves. So you need to lock the chosen records after they have chosen the seat(s) before they proceed to check-out. (please think how to lock the records, and how to unlock the locked records after a certain period of inactivity).

Comment: @KenLee as an option, seat locks may be implemented through the ajax request(event when seat is chosen) which adds record to some table where locked seats(some kind of basket) list is stored. Single record in this table also stores a date and time when its been locked. And some cronjob and/or queue required to unlock seats.